# navigation stack build errors

Tags: ros, navigation, catkin-make, build, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build the navigation stack from [ros-planning/navigation/tree/indigo-devel](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/indigo-devel) but am having problems with libraries:

```
ros/catkin_ws/src/navigation/map_server/src/image_loader.cpp:43:27: fatal error: SDL/SDL_image.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
```

Solved that with `apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev`

But I cannot get past this one:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lorocos-bfl
```

It comes up while trying to compile the `robot_pose_ekf` package.  Removing that package allows the entire nav stack to build.  The same problem is referenced [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/204942/orocos-bfl/)

but the answer is to build `robot_pose_ekf` separately.  There should be a better way, so that the entire nav stack builds with `catkin_make`.

Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219312/navigation-stack-build-errors/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2015-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-18**:
Have you run `rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src` before trying to build? That should resolve any missing dependency issues (and would've told you about `sdl-image` missing).

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-10-20**:
What Distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TRY THIS.

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-bfl
```

---

Originally posted by [Azhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27936/azhar/) with karma: 100 on 2017-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0